# Use match from file in string

Tags: linux, bash, macos, awk

I have a list of user ids in a file and I'm trying to generate some sql from the file.

```
cat users.json | awk '/UID/{print "INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES ("$2");" }'
```

But it's not doing what I expected it to do:

```
);SERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES ("1"
);SERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES ("2"
```

The query I am trying for is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES ([userID]);
```

example json if it helps:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "UID": "abc"
    },
    {
      "UID": "124"
    }
  ],
  "objectsCount": 5,
  "totalCount": 10966,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "statusReason": "OK"
}
```

Am I using the right tool? If I am, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: No you aren't, use a json parser like jq

Comment: Show us the json input and how the query should be

Comment: @Inian I've updated the question.

Comment: @guided1: Your `JSON` input is syntactically incorrect, check it in https://jsonlint.com/ and fix it

Comment: @Inian the question is not about json. The question is about getting values out of a file. and embedding it into a string... also it's fixed.

Comment: @guided1: where did you get the json input from? If I understand right? from the json above? you want to get lines as queries containing the  UID values right? Download and install `jq` to solve this

Comment: @Inian the actual json is fine btw... I just removed sensitive information when putting it here.

Comment: @guided1: Am afraid still not, the json has unicode double-quotes, replace it with normal ones like " for parsers to parse this

Comment: @Inian ahh yeah... textedit in mac. I've turned if off a few times and it keeps coming back

Answer (score 2):

Your `JSON` input has a couple of issues which makes it impossible to parse them using parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) which on `OS X` you can install by `brew install jq`

The error free `JSON` from your question would be

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "UID": "abc"
    },
    {
      "UID": "124"
    }
  ],
  "objectsCount": 5,
  "totalCount": 10966,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "statusReason": "OK"
}
```

To parse this `JSON` and produce two statements as queries containing the UID values, just do

```
jq --raw-output '"INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (" + (.results[] | .UID) + ")"' users.json
```

would produce an output as

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (abc)
INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (124)
```

The addition operator `+` in `jq` allows you to concatenate strings to form the final string.

[`jq` snippet from jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/lyh6w7-Zaj).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: '/UID/ {print "INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES ("gensub(" ","","g",$2)");"}' users.json
```

Use gensub to take the spaces out of second : delimited field. Note also that you don't need to cat the file to awk it.

Answer (score 0):

You have several JSON parsers available to you on OS X that will also work on Linux. You can use Perl, Python or Ruby among others.

Here is a demo in Ruby:

Given:

```
$ cat json 
{
    "results": [
        {
            "UID": "abc"
        },
        {
            "UID": "124"
        }
    ],
    "objectsCount": 5,
    "totalCount": 10966,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "errorCode": 0,
    "statusReason": "OK"
}
```

You can parse that file and print to lines of interest this way:

```
$ ruby -0777 -lane 'require "json"
                    d=JSON.parse($_)
                    d["results"].each {|e| puts "INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (#{e["UID"]})" }' json
INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (abc)
INSERT IGNORE INTO potential_problem_users VALUES (124)
```

Answer (score 0):

`users.json` contains carriage returns (aka `\r`s aka `control-M`s), run `dos2unix` or similar on it first then re-run your awk script (or run any other script) on it and then let us know if you still have a problem.

Almost every time you find characters you expect to see at the end of a line showing up at the start instead the problem is control-Ms.